# "this." in Javascript Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

In this case, what does the `this` inside the `$.get` function refer to?

```
var articles, verbs, nouns, prepositions, adjectives, words;
articles = ["the", "a"];

this.importData = function() {
    $.get("generator/parts_of_speech/verbs.txt", function(data) {
        this.verbs = data.split("\n");
        **//what does this "this" refer to???**
    });
};

this.importData();
```

When I write `alert(verbs)` outside of the `$.get` function, or even `alert(this.verbs)`, the alert shows up as undefined. I have tried all four cases:

1. inside the `$.get` function, write `verbs = data.split("\n")` and outside of it, write `alert(verbs)`
2. inside the `$.get` function, write `verbs = data.split("\n")` and outside of it, write `alert(this.verbs)`
3. inside the `$.get` function, write `this.verbs = data.split("\n")` and outside of it, write `alert(verbs)`
4. inside the `$.get` function, write `this.verbs = data.split("\n")` and outsideof it, write `alert(this.verbs)`

And all four of these situations give me an undefined in the alert. What is going on?

Comment: why do you even try to access `this` in your case?

Comment: Where are you putting your alert? You know `$.get()` will be asynchronous, right? So you need to do any processing inside the get callback (or in other functions called from there), or use `.done()`...

Comment: @nnnnnn huh... haven't though of that part. I did put it right after this.importData(). All I'm trying to do is put the data retrieved from the text file into the local variable "verbs". Should I or should I not use "this" to do this?

Comment: No, you don't need `this`. The `verbs` variable is already in scope. It's just that at the point that you try to alert it it has not yet been assigned a value because the callback hasn't been called yet.

Comment: What should I do, then, if I want to use the `verbs` variable outside of this script? When I try to use it, how can I ensure that the data will be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get()` is asynchronous: Your code isn't going to wait there until `$.get` sees a result. That result will come back a little bit later -- that's why you give it a callback, because it's not like a regular function call where the code waits until the result is handed directly to the caller. To stretch a metaphor, it's a bit like you're leaving a message. The server will be contacted, and the browser (via jQuery, yada) will call your callback in the near future when it gets a response from the server. In the meantime, your code will already have gone ahead and called `alert` -- before the response has been received.

So, on to `this`. `this.verbs` is not the same as plain `verbs`. Plain `verbs` will refer to the one you declared in the var statement. They have nothing to do with each other. They have the same name, but they are different people living on different streets. As it happens, when you assign to `this.verbs`, you're creating it as a member of [a settings object internal to `$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). That doesn't get you anything. Outside of the callback, `this` will refer to the global `window` object, unless you're writing your own class, which I doubt.

If you wanted to store `verbs` in a place where other code can get to it, the plain `verbs` at the top is the one to use.

The way jQuery uses `this` is very unclear to new programmers, and [there's a solid argument that it's a design flaw](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2009/01/12/why-i-still-prefer-prototype-to-jquery). Reasonable people disagree.

Case 1 is the only case that had the slightest hope of working, because it's the only one where you're assigning to outer-scoped `verbs` and then passing the same variable to `alert`. It failed anyway, for the timing reason given above.

Try assigning a placeholder value -- `"initial verbs value"` -- to `verbs` before you call `this.importData()`. I expect that you will see that initial value in the `alert`.

Try your `alert` call INSIDE the `$.get` callback. See what you get then. I'm pretty confident you'll see whatever you're getting from the server.

The code that makes use of `verbs` should be called from that callback, the place where right now you're just assigning it to `verbs`. The following is my preference. You could just stuff it all in the callback, and lots of people do.

```
this.importData = function() {
    $.get("generator/parts_of_speech/verbs.txt", function(data) {
        doStuffWithVerbs(data.split("\n"));
    });
};

function doStuffWithVerbs(verbs) {
    //  Whatever you're doing with verbs goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - What should I do, then, if I want to use the `verbs` variable outside of this script? When I try to use it, how can I ensure that the data will be loaded?

Comment: @AlexTeichner Whatever you're doing with `verbs`, do it inside the callback where at the moment you're merely assigning to it. It would be cleaner to write another function that does all that stuff (populating UI, whatever you have in mind), and takes `verbs` as an argument.

Comment: @AlexTeichner I've altered my answer to clarify that. That's the standard thing, and it's why the callback is there: How else do you know when the result is back? $.get calls the callback, that's how.

Comment: _"...which almost certainly happens before..."_ - Which 100% definitely happens before no matter how fast the network response is. JavaScript doesn't have multithreading (ignoring web workers, which don't apply here); the callback for `$.get()` is queued up for later and will not be called until some point after the current block finishes executing.

Comment: @nnnnnn Well I'll be darned. Thanks, I'll clarify that.

Comment: Is there a way to wait until the `$.get()` function has gotten everything it needs? I have too much convoluted code to stuff it all in the callback.

Comment: No, that's all you get. The callback is called when it's ready. doStuffWithVerbs can be any size you like, but you may have to spend some time de-convoluting here.

Answer (score 1):

> what does this "this" refer to???**

It refers to the jQuery settings object.

From [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - context option

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>   $.ajax).

---

From the way your code looks, you want to assign `verbs` to the object to which the method `importData` belongs to(assuming you know about the asynchronous nature of ajax requests and [how a value set by an async method has to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)).

You can pass a custom context to the callback method using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)/[$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy)

```
this.importData = function () {
    $.get("generator/parts_of_speech/verbs.txt", $.proxy(function (data) {
        this.verbs = data.split("\n");
        //here now `this` refers to the same context on which `importData` was called
    }, this));
};
```

---

Another option to do the same is to use a closure variable like

```
this.importData = function() {
    var self = this;
    $.get("generator/parts_of_speech/verbs.txt", function(data) {
        self.verbs = data.split("\n");
        **//what does this "this" refer to???**
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the function refers to the context of that function so you can only access it either inside this function or... well in your case just inside the function.

`verbs` is undefined everywhere because you did not assign anything to it, `this.verbs` outside the `$.get` is undefined due to the reason above (in other words it's out of its scope)...

so in other words only if you call `alert(this.verbs)` inside the `$.get`, you will get some results

Answer (score 0):

In your case, "this" is referring to the global window object. If you went to the console and put in.

```
this
```

It will return the window object.

However, inside the $.get it is scoped to the current function.

```
window.importdata = function() { 
 $.get('sdfs', function() { console.log(typeof this) } 
)};
```

Logs "Object" but its the xHr object.

All of the variables you have declared are in the global scope. (Window Scope)

```
var articles, verbs, nouns, prepositions, adjectives, words;
```

But you are trying to access this.verbs from within a different scope and this.verbs doesn't exist in that function.

Hitting this in the console will return undefined. Which means it has been declared, but there is no value assigned to it.

```
this.verbs
```

But inside your function you will get an error I believe. Since you declared those vars in the global scope they are available inside your function just loose the "this" .

```
verbs = data.split("\n");
```

I hope this helps.